# only one instance of a scriptmanager can be added to the page Ajax + Telerik

Tags: asp.net, ajax, telerik, scriptmanager

I'm trying to use Ajax accordion and the telerik RadScriptmanager to have an AJAX dynamic accordion and drag and drop control.  This is what I have in my .aspx but i'm not able to figure out how to use both script managers.  Thanks!

```
<td width="29%" height="135">
    <ajaxToolKit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager2" runat="Server" />
<Scripts>
            <ajaxToolkit:Accordion ID="NavigateAccordion" runat="server" 
                                       HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader" 
                                       ContentCssClass="accordionContent" 
                                       FadeTransitions="true" 
                                       SuppressHeaderPostbacks = "true" 
                                       AutoSize="None"
                                       Width="220">
                                            </ajaxToolkit:Accordion>
</td>
<td width="71%">
    &nbsp;</td>


                            <form id="form2" runat="server">
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">

        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js" />
    </Scripts>
</telerik:RadScriptManager>
<telerik:RadFormDecorator ID="RadFormDecorator1" runat="server" DecoratedControls="Buttons" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use both script managers; since both inherit from `System.Web.UI.ScriptManager`, and `ScriptManager` expects only one instance of itself (defined internally), this scenario will never work.  Use one or the other.  You don't need to have an `ToolkitScriptManager` for the AJAX control toolkit to work; however, the script manager has to be at the top of the page, before the other AJAX controls.

Answer (score 0):

You only need 1 script manager in your page (most likely in a master page).

You then want to use the built in ASP.NET Script Mananger proxy classes to talk to it from a webform page.

**Edit**: Regarding your comment, I would look at just trying moving the

```
<Scripts>
...
</Scripts>
```

Block into the the ajax tool kit script manager.

More along these lines:

```
<ajaxToolKit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager2" runat="Server">
    <Scripts>
      <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.Core.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQuery.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" Name="Telerik.Web.UI.Common.jQueryInclude.js" />
    </Scripts> 
</ajaxToolKit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

And remove the usage of the RadScriptManager

Comment: Completely greek to me, i'm also not using a masterpage, isn't there a different between the telerik scriptmanager and the ajax script manager?

Comment: I might not have gotten your answer correctly, please see my edit, what i did doesn't compile.  Thanks!